# Using Random Numbers in Theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano, deep-learning

I am a theano newbie.

Can someone please explain the following code?

```
from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams
from theano import function
srng = RandomStreams(seed=234)
rv_u = srng.uniform((2,2))
rv_n = srng.normal((2,2))
f = function([], rv_u)
g = function([], rv_n, no_default_updates=True)    #Not updating rv_n.rng
nearly_zeros = function([], rv_u + rv_u - 2 * rv_u)

state_after_v0 = rv_u.rng.get_value().get_state()
nearly_zeros()       # this affects rv_u's generator
v1 = f()
rng = rv_u.rng.get_value(borrow=True)
rng.set_state(state_after_v0)
rv_u.rng.set_value(rng, borrow=True)
v2 = f()             # v2 != v1
v3 = f()             # v3 == v1
```

Q1. How does nearly_zeros() affect rv_u's generator?
Q2. Why ?

```
v2 != v1
v3 == v1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

Looks like only 1 "value" (ie a 2x2 matrix) is being generated by rv_u's generator.  You can see this if you use `theano.printing.debugprint` to print the graph of the function.  For reference this is what I got:

```
>>> theano.printing.debugprint(nearly_zeros)
Elemwise{Composite{((i0 + i0) - (i1 * i0))}}[(0, 0)] [@A] ''   1
 |RandomFunction{uniform}.1 [@B] ''   0
 | |<RandomStateType> [@C]
 | |TensorConstant{(2,) of 2} [@D]
 | |TensorConstant{0.0} [@E]
 | |TensorConstant{1.0} [@F]
 |TensorConstant{(1, 1) of 2.0} [@G]
RandomFunction{uniform}.0 [@B] ''   0
```

This means the two functions (nearly_zero and f) both grab only 1 value from rv_u, hence why

```
v3 == v1
```

**Q2**

Theano is largely a symbolic math package.  You define relationships between symbolic variables and Theano figures out how to evaluate those relationships.

So you could consider rv_u to be a variable which represents a single 2x2 matrix, rather than a rng which generates a new 2x2 matrix each time it's "called."  Given that view, Theano would only need to call the underlying rng once to get the value for the variable rv_u.

Answer (score 0):

### Q1

When `nearly_zeros()` is called, it uses the current rng state of the random stream to return a new `rv_u` and increments the state just as it does for the function `f`.  The easiest way to see what is happening to `rv_u` is to add it as an output to the `nearly_zeros()` function.  Although `rv_u` is present three times, the value of `rv_u` is sampled from the random stream only once, hence `nearly_zero` will indeed be nearly zero (up to floating-point quantization error.)

```
nearly_zeros = function([], [rv_u, rv_u + rv_u - 2 * rv_u])
f() # The return value will be different from the rv_u in the list above
```

If you do not intend for it to increment, you can specify the `no_default_updates=True` as was done for `g`.

```
nearly_zeros = function([], [rv_u, rv_u + rv_u - 2 * rv_u], 
     no_default_updates=True)
f() # The return value will be equal to the rv_u in the list above
```

### Q2

The "why" here was a little ambiguous, so I present two possibilities with the answers.

#### Q2(a)

Why does using `nearly_zeros()` impact `rv_u` in this way?

`rv_u` is a uniform srng object which uses a shared variable that is incremented each time it is requested, unless specifically told otherwise (by means of the `no_defalut_updates` parameter.)  This is true whether `f` or `nearly_zero` happens to be the function that requests the value of `rv_u`.

#### Q2(b)

Why is the following true:

```
v2 != v1
v3 == v1
```

This is because your code saves the state after defining `nearly_zeros` but before it is called.  When the state is set, the first value that is returned is the value used by `nearly_zeros` (which is equal to `v2`.)  The next value requested will be equal to the value of `v3`.  The following is a nearly identical copy of your code, and it should prove illustrative:

```
from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams
from theano import function
srng = RandomStreams(seed=234)
rv_u = srng.uniform((2,2))
rv_n = srng.normal((2,2))
f = function([], rv_u)
g = function([], rv_n, no_default_updates=True)    #Not updating rv_n.rng
nearly_zeros = function([], [rv_u, rv_u + rv_u - 2 * rv_u]) # Give rv_u, too

state_after_v0 = rv_u.rng.get_value().get_state()
nearly_zeros()       # this affects rv_u's generator
v1 = f()
rng = rv_u.rng.get_value(borrow=True)
rng.set_state(state_after_v0)
rv_u.rng.set_value(rng, borrow=True)
v2 = f()             # v2 != v1, but equal to rv_u used by nearly_zeros
v3 = f()             # v3 == v1
```

*Aside: Although this thread is a bit old, hopefully someone will find these answers helpful.*